# JavaFX how to bind TextProperty to append to TextField (not to set)

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TextField named eventLog with binded StringProperty from the other Class. This class looks like this:

```
public class LogInfo {
    private static StringProperty logData = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public static StringProperty logDataProperty() {
        return logData;
    }

    public static void setLogData(String data) {
        logData.set(data);
    }

    public static String getLogData() {
        return logData.get();
    }
}
```

On my JavaFX controller class it's started like this:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        eventLog.textProperty().bind(LogInfo.logDataProperty());
        LogInfo.setLogData("Some informations");
    }
```

It's working great, but each time I use LogInfo.setLogData(String data) it's added to my TextField and clearing previous info, I need to append it. Is there any way to append instead of adding and clearing TextField ?

Comment: Maybe you could `.addListener()` on the `logDataProperty()` instead of binding

Comment: before setting the new data,get the existing data to temp string and append to latest and then set.
String _logData = LogInfo.getLogData();
LogInfo.setLogData(_logData+"Some informations");

Comment: Thank you, so simple and working :) logData.set(getLogData() + data);

Comment: Does he need the temp var? Shouldn 't it work by using logdata.set(getLogData()+data) ?

Comment: There's no need for temp var. Set is clearing current data so set(getLogData() + data) copies current data, appends new to this copied and updates - all in one.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can play with the output of the StringProperty, i recommend you this way:

```
public static void setLogData(String data) {
    logData.set(logData.get()+data);
}
```